# How to show exception in jwt laravel 5.4 api in postmen

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

In my laravel app i have installed jwt packages and set the middleware but the the token is invalid or expired or not sent it shows an error not in JSON format bellow are the details of my problems. Every things is working correctly but exception not throw in json format.Exception thrown as error like this (`Could not decode token: Error while decoding to JSON: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`) that is the issue.

this is my jwtMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try 
        {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } 
        catch (\JWTException $e) 
        {
            if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException)
            {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }
            else if ($e instanceof \Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException)
            {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }
            else
            {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
                return response()->json(['status' => $e]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

this is the error shows as shown in image
[shown exception as error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzshw.png)

and expected error like this
[required exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMK8g.png)

sending postman request
[sending to postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgeGC.png)

Comment: Have you tried using Switch instead nested if's? With Switch you have a default value, maybe is an error that you haven't handle.

Comment: i did not use nay switch statement if i want then how to use

Comment: I know you didn't use it, thats why i suggested you to use it. If you don't want to, then add this line after your last `else`: `return response()->json(['status' => $e]);`

Comment: i added but not work

Comment: Change `catch (Exception $e)` to `catch (JWTException $e)`

Comment: i have used but not work

Answer (score 0):

Check that the request that you're sending has this header

```
{ Authorization: 'Bearer TOKEN' }
```

How to add this header in Axios:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  if (store.getters.authToken) {
    request.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.getters.authToken}`
  }

  return request
})
```

Check that your .htaccess has the rule

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Remember that TOKEN is the token that you get in the login

Comment: Update your question with the ajax call please

Comment: JWT Token its supposed to work with ajax calls, not with regular http requests.. Im talking about the request that you are sending to that controller.

Comment: it is passing through postmen.

Comment: Can you post a capture of the Postman request so we can help you better..

Comment: any one please help??

Comment: Can you attach captures of postman , pressing the buton headers(8) and raw, can you login again and test with another token

Answer (score 0):

`I show my exception in json formate below way, you can try with this. to show exception in jwt you give this in catch JWTException`

```
$credentials = $request->only('user_name', 'password');
            try {
                if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    return response()->json([
                        'code'      => 404,
                        'response'  => 'error',
                        'errors'    => ['massage' => 'invalid email/ or password.']
                    ]);
                }
            } catch (JWTException $e) {
                return response()->json([
                    'code'      => 500,
                    'response'  => 'error',
                    'errors'    => ['massage' => 'failed to create token.']
                ]);
            }
```

Comment: token is creating but exception is not throw in json format

Comment: this is working with my authcontroller but exception not thrown in json